# Find analytic function such that $u = \phi \left( \frac{x^2+y^2}{x} \right) $

Tags: complex-analysis

Find analytic function $w= u+iv$  such that $u = \phi \left( \frac{x^2+y^2}{x} \right) $

My idea
$\Delta u = 0$
$u_{xx} + u_{yy} = 0$
but it gets complicated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From equation $u_{xx} + u_{yy} = 0$ we get ode
$$\phi''(t)=-\frac{2\phi'(t)}{t},\quad t=\frac{x^2+y^2}{x}.$$

Then $$\phi(t)=\frac{c_1}{t}+c_2,$$
$$u=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}.$$